# String not getting replaced with sed command

Tags: bash, sed

In my script, I am using below sed command

```
while read line; do
  echo "$line"
  sed -r "s/where /where $line ;/" Query.cql > Query-2.cql
done < $1
```

the value of **$line** is

> where Column11 in ('Value1','Value2','Vlaue3')  and Column12 in
> ('Value11','Value22','Vlaue32')

File Content ::

> capture 'data.csv'
>
> select * from test where
>
> capture off;

After Executing

```
sed -r "s/where /where $line ;/" Query.cql > Query-2.cql
```

OUTPUT is ::

> capture 'data.csv'
>
> select * from test where
>
> capture off;

Here, the string is not getting replaced.
What went wrong?

Comment: Could you specify your wanted result ? it's confused.

Comment: sed -e "s/where /$line ;/" normalQuery.cql > qWithWhere.cql

Comment: Put the sed statement in quotes when you are expanding variables.

Comment: @apapillon ..... no luck with above mentioned command :(

Comment: @apapillon ......thanks it worked

Comment: No need to embed `sed` inside a `while read` loop, imagine if that file contains 1k lines, then `sed` will have to process each line, so `sed` will run 1k times too....

Comment: @apapillon... its working out side the script but in script it isn't

Comment: @Jetchisel.. I need to prepare where query for each where clause and there will be at most 100 clause... that will be 100 lines... so is there any other way to do ?

Comment: Generating a single SQL file with all your commands would seem a lot simpler as well as more robust and efficient. If the input is complex, maybe switch from `sed` to Awk or a more modern scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated `s' command

Sure the `s` command is `s/<something>/<else>/` - there is a trailing `/`. Do:

```
sed -r 's/where /$line ;/'
                        ^ - trailing /
```

The `-r` option seems unused - `where` has no extended regular expressions. If so, remove it.

Your command uses `'` quotes, so `$line` is not expanded. Research the difference between single and double quotes in shell, most probably you meant to use `"` here.

Note that each loop `> qWithWhere.cql` is recreating result and overwriting the result from previous loop. You might just run the loop on the last line them.

Read [how to read a file line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) and how to [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern) .

---

The following code with a space after `where` in input:

```
cat <<EOF >input
capture 'data.csv'
select * from test where 
capture off;
EOF
line="where Column11 in ('Value1','Value2','Vlaue3') and Column12 in ('Value11','Value22','Vlaue32')"
sed -r "s/where /where $line ;/" input
```

outputs:

```
capture 'data.csv'
select * from test where where Column11 in ('Value1','Value2','Vlaue3') and Column12 in ('Value11','Value22','Vlaue32') ;
capture off;
```

Comment: its not  working .. i'll update the question to show you output

Comment: `What went wrong?` Well, is there a `where` __and a space after it__ in your source file? You are matching `/where /`

Comment: yes.. u are right I forgot 'space'... its working